# RSpec : want to have many tests for one shot method, including fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, fixtures

I'm working on a Rails app.
I want to test with rspec my method "start!" of my model Backup.

So here the specs (all are methods, too):

- `Backup` should copy files to folder /backups
- `Backup` should check md5 sum
- `Backup` should delete original files

For my tests, I create fake files, based on fixtures :

```
MyFile.all.each{|r| system("touch #{r.path}") }
```

Then, `@backup.start!` should delete some of this files (not all).

The problem is : I don't want to re-run all the opérations for each test !
I could write one big test, with all the requirements include in it, but it would be ugly...

The `before(:all)` pattern, event in contexts runs before all contexts, and fixtures are not available, for design reasons.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If each method are separate, you can mock all except one and change the one each time.

You can choose and limit with method you want test.

Comment: Do you suggest to run tests once at a time ?

Comment: It sounds like re-running all operations (but one) each time ! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to http://thefrontiergroup.com.au/blog/2010/01/using-rspec-example-groups-for-common-functionality/,

I found the solution :

```
# /spec/support/backuped_files_examples.rb
shared_examples_for "backed up up files" do
  before(:all) do
    # Fixtures are unreachable for now, 
    # but test db can be use and is filled with fixtures
    MyFile.all.each{|r| system("touch #{r.path}") }
    @backup = Backup.create(...) 
    @backup.start!
  end
end

# /spec/models/backup_spec.rb
describe Backup do  
  context " (when #start! have been called)" do

    before(:each) do
      @files_to_backup = MyFile.all(:conditions => (...))
    end

    it_should_behave_like "backed up up files"
    it "should have deleted wanted files" do
      @files_to_backup.each do |file|
        File.exists(file.path).should be_false
      end
    end
  end
end
```